# fork () in C: Counting from 1 to 1000

Tags: c, process, fork

I think i am very close, but some detail is missing here.

The task:
Write a program in C that creates a father and child process. Father and child are both counting from 1 to 1000 "using" a loop.
The father process only counts the even numbers, while the child process only counts the odd numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


void main (){

int id = fork();
int i;

if (id == 0){

    for (i=1;i<=1000;i=i+2){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}

if (id >  0){

    for (i=0;i<=1000;i=i+2){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    wait(0);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem i have here is, that all the numbers a completely mixed up.
It seems that my wait system call is not working correctly :(
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `main()` should be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Read the documentation for `wait()`; it doesn't do what you seem to think.  Assumning what you want is to see all the numbers in order, you need some form of synchronization between the two processes, such as a semaphore.  There will be quite a bit of work to do to get it properly; I'm afraid you're not exactly "close" yet.

Comment: This shouldn't make them all mixed up. It shold either be all odd numbers first, or all odd numbers between 0 and 2.

Comment: Are you expecting the numbers to be printed in order? Nothing in the task says this is a requirement.

Comment: Yeah that is what i am expecting. So i need a semaphore here?

Comment: the OP:s posted code is missing the case of `fork()` returning an error indication,  The code must not be allowed to 'fall through' from the code for the child to the code for the parent process.

Comment: The assignment is not asking for the numbers to be printed in order, so you should not complicate the assignment be inserting your favorite extra criteria

Comment: Ok lets assume that i have to print the numbers in the correct ordner. What am i missing here? Is it a semaphore? I am completely lost right now :(

Answer (score -1):

```
Your wait system call should placed out of for loop, because there's only one child process to wait.
like that 

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    
    
    void main (){
    
    int id = fork();
    int i;
    
    if (id == 0){
    
        for (i=1;i<=1000;i=i+2){
        printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    
    if (id >  0){
    
        for (i=0;i<=1000;i=i+2){
        printf("%d\n",i);
       
        }
        wait(0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.